# Compare/differentiate two "identical" CLBeacons

Tags: core-location, ibeacon

Is it possible to differentiate "identical" CLBeacons? Meaning, CLBeacons with same UUID, major and minor, but coming from different devices?

In the CLBeacon Class Reference I can read, that there is a property accuracy which could be used for that. But, let's say, both devices are on top of each other in the same spot (probably not a real world situation), is this still a reliable argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not possible with CoreLocation APIs.**  If you have two different beacons with the same ProximityUUID/major/minor combination, each one will show up independently in an iOS ranging callback, but you will have no way of knowing which is which because no other identifiers are available that can distinguish them.

Although the internal CoreLocation implementation is not published, my tests suggest that CoreLocation keys unique beacons off of the Bluetooth Mac address, allowing it to realize that two different beacons broadcasting the same identifiers are not just one beacon.  Unfortunately, CoreLocation does not allow you to read this Mac address.

And while you can read the Mac address (or at least a derivation of it) with CoreBluetooth APIs, you cannot read the iBeacon identifiers, so it is impossible to correlate the two.  (See: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html )

The bottom line is that if you want to distinguish two iBeacons on iOS, you must give therm different identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for this pro answer and for clarifying the situation! I wanted to use major and minor as a reference to content in a database. Your comment lead me in to a much better solution by dumping my first approach completely. But, that's programming, I think.

Comment: @davidgyoung theoretically if I was an hardware producer I could create an SDK that exposes macaddresses, a bit like Estimote does with the ESTBeacon class. Correct?

Comment: I don't see any way to do this.  I am not an expert on Estimote beacons, but my understanding is that the mac address is only populated after you use CoreBluetooth to connect to the beacon, not when you are scanning for the beacon.  While it is possible to build a beacon that lets you connect to it and expose the mac address with a custom GATT attribute that includes it, there is no way to use this in regular scanning situations.  Connecting to a beacon stops it from advertising, so only one mobile device at a time could use this technique to read the mac.

Answer (score 1):

You could try examining the advertising data via Core Bluetooth but from a location point of view if they have the same UUID, major and minor then they are the same region and it makes no sense to try and differentiate them

Comment: Thanks, I now have a completely new approach to my litte iBeacon project.